# Increase width of ag-grid filter with specific column

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I want to increase width of ag-grid filter with specific column [image]

I have tried to fix with css but its affecting with every column.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Right click on filter input and click inspect. You will see an id generated, in my case the id of input is "ag-20-input". You can use this id to change width of specific column filter.

```
#ag-20-input{
    max-width: 2px !important;
}
```